# allowing root login in joyent with vagarant

Tags: vagrant, ubuntu-14.04, vagrantfile, joyent

I am creating instances through vagrant using vagrant up --provider=joyent

vagarant needs root user .. but bye default joyent accepting only ubuntu user.. is there any way that joyent accepts root user by default before creating instance

Answer (score 0):

by default joyent wont allow root user so after after vagrant up.. we need to login to the instance.. and we need to copy authorized_keys file root fixes the problem